# ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure test(supplierid in number,
                                 supplier   out varchar) is
begin
  select first_name
    into Supplier
    from lup_sup_master
   where sup_id = supplierid;
end;
/ 

execute test(2279, :supplierid);
```

or

```
begin
execute test(2279, :supplierid); dbms_output.enable; dbms_output.put_line(supplier);
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your procedure `test` has 2 input arguments. One has type IN which is supposed to be used with the procedure and the other parameter `supplier` has type `OUT` which means this parameter is suppose to hold the value which the `Procedure` returns.

As explained by @Barbaros, if you want to execute the Procedure via a SQL command prompt, you can follow the steps.

However the second way you showed was using a  `PLSQL Block`.

> begin
>
> execute test(2279, :supplierid);
>
> dbms_output.enable;
>
> dbms_output.put_line(supplier); end;

In the above example of calling, you must note that `Execute` keyword is only be used whenever you use a `SQL` command line prompt. While using a PLSQL block you cal directly call the Procedure by its name as shown below. Also note that incase you have a `OUT` parameter, you must have `OUT` parameter passed to the `Procedure` since the `Procedure` is expecting 2 arguments. See below demo.

```
declare
 var varchar2(100);
begin
 test( supplierid => 2279, supplier =>var); 
 dbms_output.enable; 
 dbms_output.put_line(var);
End;
```

Comment: thanks yes i am asking about pl/sql  its working need to confirm one thing on execution time we need to declare out parameters again as i already declared parameter in procedure at call time is it must to declare again parameters?

Comment: @shabanaAfzal Yes its mandatory to declare all the parameter which are input to the Procedure. So in your case you declared an `OUT` parameter so that has to be passed to the procedure explicitly.

Comment: how we can pass multiple values in a parameter of procedure.as in above case in procedure i want to pass multiple supplier_id using in in-spite of equal to.

Comment: @shabanaAfzal In that case you need to pass a table of string to your procedure. Google down you would find many articles to do that. Incase you dont find any post a new question with lastest requirement with examples.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're confused between `supplierid` and `supplier`. You need to define a variable for `supplier` to get an output line printed, and most probably you defined a command line variable `supplierid` which's numeric type.

So, use below :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> var supplier varchar2;
SQL> execute test(2279, :supplier);
supplier
---------
Afzal -- as an example name
```